# Accessing MySQL database from PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am making a small database application for the experience, but I am having a problem with actually accessing the database from my PHP code. I've tried accessing the file name, accessing the separate mysql file. But whatever I do, I get an error message

```
<?php

$password = md5("passhash");
$user = array("name"=> "JohnDoe", "password" => $password, "email" => "email@email.com");


try {
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=users.ibd; port=8889", "root", "root");
  ...
}
```

**Unable to connectSQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'users.ibd'**

Do you guys have any experience with this error message and what I could possibly be doing wrong when it comes to declaring the database name in my PDO initialization?

Comment: Looks like there is not a DB called users.ibd.  Are you sure this is the DB name?

Comment: maybe database name are only "users"?

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a uselessly weak hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind when I switch from writing basic PHP to Laravel(which is the framework I'm going to move to). I just wanted to whip up a quick little hobby project and didn't care if the hash was strong or not.

Answer (score 1):

please check on your db name... if exist on your list of database.
Try to check out on mysql console with command **SHOW DATABASES;**

You should connect with the table which apears on mysql console, not with the file on mysql folder.

Answer (score -1):

I looked. The .ibd was actually throwing off what was database name. Thanks Guys for the help.